# connect a radiobutton to a combobox

Tags: java, swing

I'm making a program about conversion (mass, measurement, or volume) in java Swing. I want when to click at either of those mass, measurement, or volume
the options (g, kg, t) (cm, m, km) (cl, dl, l) change when i click

```
JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton("masse");
r1.setBounds(34, 43, 109, 23);
f.add(r1);

JRadioButton r2 = new JRadioButton("mesure");
r2.setBounds(34, 69, 109, 23);
f.add(r2);

JRadioButton r3 = new JRadioButton("volume");
r3.setBounds(34, 94, 109, 23);
f.add(r3);
ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(r1);bg.add(r2);bg.add(r3);
f.setLayout(null); 
final JComboBox list2 = new JComboBox();
list2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"choisir ", "kg", "g", "t"}));
list2.setBounds(193, 172, 64, 22);
f.add(list2);
final JComboBox list2 = new JComboBox();
list2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"choisir ", "cm", "m", "km"}));
list2.setBounds(193, 172, 64, 22);
f.add(list2);
final JComboBox list2 = new JComboBox();
list2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"choisir ", "cl", "dl", "l"}));
list2.setBounds(193, 172, 64, 22);
f.add(list2);
```

[image]

Comment: you can add a listener to the buttons ( `addActionListener()`) that will then change the elements of the combo box (`removeAllItems()`, `addItem()` ....) But not clear what exactly is the question here?

Comment: my questions  is how i connect the radiobutton with the combobox , when i click to a radionbutton the options in combobox change each time

Comment: That code is not readable. Please format it and [edit] your question telling the details of the code and the problem. Have you added a listener to the JRadioButton or its model yet?

Comment: What you want to do is add a listener to set the radiobutton's action commands to match their title, add an action listener the radio buttons, and get the action command from the action event parameter or from the ButtonModel that the radio button's button group tells you has been selected. Then change the combo box's model based on the selection. The Swing tutorials will help you learn about each of these steps.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, you can do the following:

- Declare a `DefaultComboBoxModel` field in your program. This will allow you to change this model that your `JComboBox` uses as the program runs
- Create a `JComboBox` that uses this same model
- Create your `JRadioButtons`, assign them to the same `ButtonGroup` and give them an `ActionListener` that

  - First clears the combo box model
  - Then assigns the appropriate Strings into the same model

For example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RadioCombo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("RadioCombo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new RadioComboPanel());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class RadioComboPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final Map <String, List<String>> SELECTIONS = Map.of(
        "A", List.of("A1", "A2", "A3"),
        "B", List.of("B1", "B2", "B3"),
        "C", List.of("C1", "C2", "C3")
    );
    private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
    private JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(model);

    public RadioComboPanel() {
        // create a sorted map, if desired -- this is not 100% necessary
        Map<String, List<String>> sortedSelections = new TreeMap<>(SELECTIONS);
        JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        for (String key : sortedSelections.keySet()) {
            JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(key);
            button.setActionCommand(key);
            button.addActionListener(e -> {
                model.removeAllElements();
                for (String value : SELECTIONS.get(key)) {
                    model.addElement(value);
                }
            });
            group.add(button);
            radioPanel.add(button);
        }

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(combo, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
}
```

The key of this code is here:
The `model` variable is the model used by the JComboBox

```
private DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
private JComboBox<String> combo = new JComboBox<>(model);
```

The ActionListener below is called when a radio button is selected, and within this listener, the model is first emptied with `model.removeAllElements()`. Then the new items are added to the model by the for loop that follows: `for (String value : SELECTIONS.get(key)) { ....`

```
button.addActionListener(e -> {
    model.removeAllElements();
    for (String value : SELECTIONS.get(key)) {
        model.addElement(value);
    }
});
```

---

Side notes:

- Do not use null layouts and `setBounds(...)` to position your GUI components. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, they won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they result in GUI's that are difficult to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- Instead you will want to study and learn the layout managers and then nest `JPanels`, each using its own layout manager to create pleasing and complex GUI's that look good on all OS's.
- Avoid hard-coding your model values as you're currently doing.

Answer (score 1):

Store your ComboBox choices in variables, so you can reuse them:

```
JRadioButton r1 = new JRadioButton("masse");
JRadioButton r2 = new JRadioButton("mesure");
JRadioButton r3 = new JRadioButton("volume");

r1.setSelected(true);

ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
bg.add(r1);
bg.add(r2);
bg.add(r3);

String[] u1 = {"choisir ", "kg", "g", "t"};
String[] u2 = {"choisir ", "cm", "m", "km"};
String[] u3 = {"choisir ", "cl", "dl", "l"};

JComboBox<String> list1 = new JComboBox<>(u1);
JComboBox<String> list2 = new JComboBox<>(u1);

r1.addActionListener(e -> {
    list1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(u1));
    list2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(u1));
});
r2.addActionListener(e -> {
    list1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(u2));
    list2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(u2));
});
r3.addActionListener(e -> {
    list1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(u3));
    list2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(u3));
});
```

An additional note:  never do this:

```
f.setLayout(null);
```

It may seem easier, but your program will not look right on other computers.  This is because fonts on other computers will take up a different number of pixels, depending on the monitor’s size.  In fact, there’s no guarantee other computers will even use the same fonts at all.  Also, other computers might use different borders and margins for buttons, text fields, and other controls.

There is already an easy solution to this:  layouts.  All components compute their own preferred size, taking into account all of the above considerations.  All you need to do is use layouts, since layouts will respect those computed sizes.

There are a handful of layouts available, but you can probably get by with a very simple layout:  [Box](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Box.html).

Here is code that assembles your window using layouts, instead of setting explicit sizes and locations:

```
Box typesBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
typesBox.add(conversionLabel);
typesBox.add(r1);
typesBox.add(r2);
typesBox.add(r3);

Box conversionBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
conversionBox.add(typesBox);
conversionBox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());

Box valueBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
valueBox.add(new JLabel("Valeur à convertir "));
valueBox.add(valueField);
valueBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(6));
valueBox.add(list1);

Box resultBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
resultBox.add(new JLabel("Résultat: "));
resultBox.add(resultField);
resultBox.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(6));
resultBox.add(list2);

Box buttonsBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
buttonsBox.add(convertButton);
buttonsBox.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
buttonsBox.add(closeButton);

Box frameContentsBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
frameContentsBox.add(conversionBox);
frameContentsBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(6));
frameContentsBox.add(valueBox);
frameContentsBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(6));
frameContentsBox.add(resultBox);
frameContentsBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(12));
frameContentsBox.add(buttonsBox);

frameContentsBox.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(12, 12, 12, 12));

f.add(frameContentsBox);
f.pack();
f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
```